# How do I specify a number of times a script should execute a function within the script without stopping? type an loop?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp

I am running a whatsapp web script to quickly create groups with a contact, but when I run the script it only creates 1 group, and so on. I want it to suddenly create multiple groups without stopping in the same function, how can I do it?

My Script Code:

https://github.com/rangoski/Python-Automation-Script/blob/master/creategroup.py

Comment: 2 things I'm noticing,1) are you sure you have multiple targets? check the list. 2) are you sure that after creating the group you get returned to a page from which you can create another group in the same manner?

Comment: It's just a target friend. I want the script to perform the same function multiple times. but he only does it once. How do I apply this repetition? no mistake

Comment: Hi please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in text in your question.